# adding href to span tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code

```
<a href="www.google.com">
    <span>Hello Clickhere</span>
</a>
```

I want to create a span tag with href without using the `<a>` tag.Somewhat like this

```
<span href="www.google.com">Hello Click</span>
```

All I want to do is to remove the `<a>` tag from the block and add the functionality to the `<span>` or the `<div>` tag

Comment: `href` is not valid with `<SPAN>`, What do you intent to achieve?

Comment: You sure have better options than doing this mess

Comment: @Satpal   I am using DOTJS as my HTML template .

Comment: Bigger question though. Why do you need to get rid of the anchor tag? What is your reasoning for removing it? Obviously you're looking to retain the functionality that's intended by the anchor tag, so what issue are you trying to resolve by removing it, and replicating it's behavior elsewhere?

Comment: @Steve-Cutter-Blades    I have a check for indexing added and that indexing works if there is no anchor tag inside the div. Event though the functionality must be retained

Comment: "check for indexing"? I don't understand. Are you saying you're trying to ensure your page is being indexed by search engines, but you don't want them to follow this anchor tag?

Comment: yes @Steve-Cutter-Blades
I am also using dotJS so,i am not able to add an onclick event on the span tag

Comment: OK, you shouldn't have to hack around an anchor to control indexing of your page. Those sorta things are handled by meta tags and sitemaps. If your page isn't getting indexed when it does have the anchor tags, then likely something about them is malformed and needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 8):

you can use `window.location`

```
 <span onclick="window.location='your http/https link'">Hello Clickhere</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create jquery function for redirecting the link and use it on span tag like this

```
<span onclick="redirectIt(this)" href="http://google.com">Hello Click here</span>
```

and jquery function will be like this

```
function redirectIt(obj){
    var goToLink = obj.getAttribute("href");
    window.location.href=goToLink;
}
```

it will talke browser to google.com by clicking on span

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is the style of a span element, then use the [CSS 'unset' property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) `all: unset;` to style your anchor element like a span. A span is just a generic unstyled inline element.

You can use this trick to style links like buttons and buttons like links while keeping their tags' [semantic functionality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics) (links to link to web pages, buttons to submit forms or run javascript).

[Google recommends](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/links-crawlable) to avoid using JavaScript redirects or invalid HTML syntax to create link-like elements when possible.

```css
/* Copied from Chrome User Agent stylesheet
with all:unset; added on the first line of
the rule to clear all other properties */
.fake-link {
    all: unset;
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.fake-span {
    all: unset;
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>

<h2>Ordinary link</h2>
<a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">go to IANA's site</a>

<h2>&lt;span&gt; styled like link</h2>
<span class="fake-link">go to IANA's site</span>

<h2>&lt;button&gt; styled like link</h2>
<button class="fake-link">go to IANA's site</button>

<h2>&lt;a&gt; styled like &lt;span&gt;</h2>
<a class="fake-span" href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">go to IANA's site</a>
```